# UITableViewController in UIPageViewController inside UINavigationController navBar doesn't bounce

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uipageviewcontroller

I have **UINavigationController** it pushes **UIPageViewController** and every page has **UITableViewController**

**NavigationController** has *prefersLargeTitles = true*

Usually with **UITableViewController** inside **NavigationController** there is this bounce animation on the navBar when dragging down.

But in my situation I don't have one on the **UITableViewController**.

Can I somehow activate the animation with this architecture?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so you should be able to access its `bounces` property.

Try something like this where you can access your tableViews:

```
yourTableView.bounces = true
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, try sharing some more code from your PageViewController

Comment: that did not work. the tableView itself bounces I have issue with navigationBar
when you drag down tableView navigationBar should get larger with the drag. I have another controllers where just UITableViewController is embedded in UINavigationController. There everything is ok. But here I have PageViewController with UITableViewControllers in its' pages. And these navBars are not dragging with tableViews